# How to increment array index

Tags: java

I am using arraylist in my java program but the problem is that when i add an item in arraylist its adding on the same index so i want to know that how to increment array index in array list.

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(500);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ":Mode set - Out of Service In Service");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    arr.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

In above code its keep adding item on the same index i.e. arr[0].

Comment: How do you know it's adding it on index 0 ?

Comment: do you want to delimit `line` by `":Mode set - Out of Service In Service"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to initalize the ArrayList size? Try your original code changing

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(500);
```

for

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: ya i know that there is no need to initialize the arraylist size. I was experimenting something. Thanks for your concern,

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code. I don't believe that it would add to position zero.

Prove it by displaying the contents: `System.out.println(arr);`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify at what index the element must be added:

```
arr.add(index,st.nextToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. I cant see any problem.
How do you know whats the value at index 0, I mean are you debugging it?
Is that text really your delimiter ?

Comment: yes that text is my delimiter. It works fine but when i tried to print values of index 0 position the whole string displayed and when i tried to print index 1 value, it shows an error.

Comment: thanks for reply. I was doing a silly mistake. Problem Solved finally.